Java: How to optimize the maximum value of i*a[i] after rotating the array?
I am trying to solve a problem where I need to find the maximum value of the sum of i*a[i] for all 0 <= i <= n-1, where a[i] is the element at index i in the array. The only allowed operation is to rotate the array (clockwise or counterclockwise) any number of times.
The code works fine for arrays with size up to 3000, but it fails for larger arrays. Out of 1115 test cases, only 1110 pass successfully.I believe the problem might be with how the current sum is being calculated in each iteration, especially for large arrays.
class Solution {
    long max_sum(int a[], int n) {
        long sum=0;
        long sum1=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            sum=sum+a[i];
            sum1=sum1+(a[i]*i);
        }
        long sumCurr=sum1;
        long sumMax=sum1;
        
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            sumCurr = sumCurr-(n*a[i])+sum;
            sum1=sumCurr;
            if(sumCurr>sumMax){
                sumMax=sumCurr;
            }
        }
        return sumMax;
    }
}

I also tried modifying the loop like this:
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    sumCurr = sumCurr + sum - n * a[n - i];
    sum1 = sumCurr;
    if (sumCurr > sumMax) {
        sumMax = sumCurr;
    }
}


How are the failing 5 test cases failing?  Are they throwing an exception?  Is there an integer overload?

if you suspect that some calculation is overflowing, you can use Math.addExact(), Math.multiplyExact() and similar to check for overflow (the operators +, *, ... do not indicate an overflow or underflow)

@RobertHarvey I actually encountered this problem on GFG. It says that when n=3296, the answer is coming out to be different . Well this code does work for other values of n , I exactly don't know the problem what is occuring here

I believe you were solving this question in GFG. I have checked the constraints of the question, which are :
1<=n<=10^5
1<=a[i]<=10^6

So at the worst case, n*a[i] = 10^5 * 10^6 = 10^11.
This will definitely overflow int (as both n and arr[i] are int, there multiplication will also be int).

Just update these two statement, and it should work fine
sum1=sum1+((long)a[i]*i);

sumCurr = sumCurr-((long)n*a[i])+sum;

